# Trouble with selecting a single wire segment of a net in Altium

Tags: altium

Below I want to select and edit only the bottom wire of three parallel wires:

[image]

But when I click on the bottom wire the program also selects the middle wire as well because they share the same net.

Is that possible to single out only a desired wire segment without selecting the entire net in Altium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

You will need to use the "Break Wire" feature first - this will split the wire up. I think it's in the "Edit" menu.